# How to limit the number of Spring @Async tasks with virtual threads enabled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-async, java-21, virtual-threads

I have an @Async task executing some database related background work. After enabling virtual threads (`spring.threads.virtual.enabled: true`) the number of Async jobs executed in parallel is no longer limited. The result is an exhausted database connection pool. When virtual threads is disabled only 8 (default) jobs are executed in parallel so less database connections are used.

What would be the recommended approach to solve this problem?

> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [task-49889]
> Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none
> available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:30000]

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestTask {

    private final MyRepository myRepository;
    @Async
    public void execute() {
        // some database calls.
        myRepository.doSomething();
    }
}
```

When executing 200 tasks the pool is exhausted.

```
IntStream.range(1, 200).forEach(value -> testTask.execute());
```

I'm using Java 21 with Spring Boot 3.2.1.

Comment: There are probably many ways to limit the number of threads in your case, including implementing rather exotic, yet pretty straightforward `FixedVirtualThreadExecutor` but I don't quite understand why would you want to use virtual threads for this particular `@Async`? The beauty of virtual threads is that they could be very many and are cheap to spin off. In this case wouldn't it be better to have a standard limited pool of ordinary, platform threads? Sorry, just very confused by your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure concurrency in this case through the [`spring.task.execution.simple.concurrency-limit`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#application-properties.core.spring.task.execution.simple.concurrency-limit) property. Default it isn't set and thus means unbounded.

Setting it in your application properties.

```
spring.task.execution.simple.concurrency-limit=8
```

This will limit it to 8 concurrent tasks (or the number you choose it to be). The auto-configuration takes [care of this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutorConfigurations.java#L180).

Comment: afaik spring.task.execution.simple.concurrency-limit is not used when virtual threads are enabled.
See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35710

Comment: You are wrong, check the code and documentation. When you enable virtual threads a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` is configured with `virtualThreads` set to `true`. Other properties, including this one, still apply.

Comment: Your answer seems to me perfectly correct, only one thing worries me in respect of OP case: this is a system-wide setting, while the particular `@Async` the OP talks about seems to me quite specific. In the OP case, I'd use custom `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`-based Executor bean, and invoke `setConcurrencyLimit` on it.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation about [Virtual Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-DC4306FC-D6C1-4BCC-AECE-48C32C1A8DAA) you have to use [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) to Limit Concurrency :

> Sometimes there is a need to limit the concurrency of a certain
> operation. For example, some external service may not be able to
> handle more than ten concurrent requests. Because platform threads are
> a precious resource that is usually managed in a pool, thread pools
> have become so ubiquitious that they're used for this purpose of
> restricting concurrency, like in the following example:

As an example something like next one approach:

```
Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(10);
...
Result foo() {
    sem.acquire();
    try {
        return callLimitedService();
    } finally {
        sem.release();
    }
}
```

Because When using virtual threads, if you want to limit the concurrency of accessing some service, you should use a construct designed specifically for that purpose: the Semaphore class.

Comment: Great solution, it is only slightly inappropriate in the particular case of `@Async` annotation. This annotation, in fact, introduces an AOP Advice; it allows a method, annotated with it, to be offloaded from any concurrency sematic and to concentrate solely on its business. With your approach, the method has to be aware of such sematic. Ideal solution would be, IMHO, to wrap this approach into `@Async` custom Executor.