# Controlling Async Processing Rate in Spring Boot with Virtual Threads

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, java-21, virtual-threads

I'm encountering an issue with excessive async processing causing : *429 Too Many Requests* errors(async logic is to call 3rd party API) in my Spring Boot application. Here are the relevant details:

```
Java version: 21
SpringBoot version: 3.2.3
Virtual Thread enabled (spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true)
```

Currently, I'm utilizing `@Async` with `Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()` to handle asynchronous tasks. However, the unrestricted thread creation under high load leads to the throttling issue.

To mitigate this, I'm considering replacing the executor with a `fixedThreadPool`. However, I'm seeking advice on more optimal methods to control the rate of async processing.

Below is the relevant code snippet:

```
@Bean
public AsyncTaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor() {
   return new TaskExecutorAdapter(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
}
```

**Update:**
Updated AyncTaskExecutor config

```
@Bean
public AsyncTaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor() {
 return new VirtualThreadTaskExecutor("async-worker");
}
```

Comment: `new TaskExecutorAdapter(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());` that renders `spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true` useless. Remove that and set a max on the threads, which will throttle the outgoing requests. Or use something like a [bulkhead](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/bulkhead) from Resilience4j to limit the concurrent calls to the outgoing API.

Comment: Could you update your answer to include an example of annotation with `@Async`? Do you specify task executor bean there like `@Async("applicationTaskExecutor")`? By default, as far as I know, bean named `taskExecutor`, which is by default `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, will be used for handling `@Async` advises. Could you confirm, possibly setting a debugger breakpoint or subclassing the adapter, that indeed adapter's methods, not `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`'s are called for `@Async`?

Comment: I made few changes to  AsyncTaskExecutor config. Check the update in question

I have not specified ```@Async``` with any bean. I can see that the logs from async worker has the same thread name pattern i mentioned in config
```2024-03-07T12:45:12.763+05:30 DEBUG 6834 --- [  async-worker0]```

Comment: OK, if you see such thread name in the log, then it looks like you use `applicationTaskExecutor` somehow, possibly directly. What confused me is that you said in your question: "I'm utilizing @Async", and then in your comment: "I have not specified @Async". In any case If you could place [an MRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example) in somewhere like github, it will greatly help to understand your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `TaskExecutorAdapter` then you might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77963407/2366397). Configuring your own `applicationTaskExecutor`, you in fact disable the default `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, which is configured from Spring Boot application properties like `spring.threads.virtual.enabled`. You might want not do it and let Spring use the default one, if so then you can find helpful [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77825750/2366397).

I think, however, that 429 Too Many Requests HTTP status is of too dynamic and unpredictable nature, and therefore no known off-the-shelf executor is capable of the correspondent dynamic tuning. The better and more natural to virtual threads way is to spawn them directly:

```
final HttpStatus[] status = new HttpStatus[1];
    
Thread.ofVirtual().start( () -> {
    // call third party, 429-prone service 
    //status[0] = ...
});
    
if (status[0] == HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS) {
    Thread.sleep(SUSPEND_TIME);
}
```

This snippet assumes that suspending a caller thread is allowed from the standpoint of your application's threading architecture.
If it is not, then, depending on your exact logic of handling 429, Circuit Breaker, Rate Limiter, Bulkhead etc patterns implemented by Resilience4j, Hystrix, Spring Retry etc might be your way to go while the simplest homemade solution might be just a single dedicated (daemon platform) thread that implements the snippet above.

> I'm considering replacing the executor with a fixedThreadPool

If you mean here `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS)`, then you plainly disable the usage of virtual threads by this executor, regardless of any property values.